# NSMutableArray writeToURL:url atomically:YES

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create a file with an NSMutableArray with just NSStrings stringWithFormat objects inside, this is what i got:

```
- (IBAction)CreateMod:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Finished Button Pressed");

    NSString* CustomScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//Made with UltimateMM \n %@",self.CS ];
    NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"js", nil];

    NSSavePanel *spanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    [spanel setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
    [spanel setCanSelectHiddenExtension:YES];
    [spanel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
    [spanel setTreatsFilePackagesAsDirectories:YES];
    [spanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.SecondaryWindow  completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
        {
            NSURL *saveURL = [spanel URL];
            NSLog(@"%@", saveURL);
            NSError* error = nil;

            if(_CST == true) {
             NSLog(@"CustomScriptMade");
                /*
                BOOL didWrite = [CustomScript writeToURL:saveURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
                if (didWrite == NO)
                {
                    NSLog(@"CustomScript Write Error");
                }
                */
            }
            if(_TTT == true) {
                NSLog(@"TopicMade");
                BOOL didWrite = [_TopicPR writeToURL:saveURL atomically:YES];
                if (didWrite == NO)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Topic Write Error");
                }
            }
            _CST = false;
            _TTT = false;
        }
    }];
}
```

I have the CustomScript writeToURL  out so i can see if it crates the TopicPR, but it doesn't even open the NSSavePanel, Please Help.

thanks in advance!..